# Problems with saving and querying dates in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an `Appointment` model, and for one particular appointment, I saved it having a `start_time` of 12:15am on 3/5/2011. Look at this:

```
irb(main):002:0> a = Appointment.find(15)
=> #<Appointment id: 15, start_time: "2011-03-05 05:15:00", created_at: "2011-03-05 03:42:03", updated_at: "2011-03-05 03:42:03", stylist_id: 13, client_id: 8>
irb(main):003:0> a.start_time
=> Sat, 05 Mar 2011 00:15:00 EST -05:00
```

As you can see, the date got saved wrong. Interestingly, though, Rails compensates for it when the data comes back out.

I assume my app has always behaved this way and I just didn't notice. Recently, though, I wrote a query that pulls the dates out with raw SQL, so I'm getting the wrong time and it's causing problems.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening and what I can do to get around the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails save datetime in database in UTC time(zero offset) and converts the time to the time zone which we intend when it displays it. So, when we parse directly from the database, you will be getting UTC time. If you try to convert it into time like this:

```
time_string = #raw string obtained from database(like "2011-03-05 05:15:00")
time_object = Time.parse(time_string)
```

You will get the time with offset according to the timezone of your machine or server. Ruby parses time like that. It will take the time and give the timezone of your machine(which is incorrect here as the timezone is actually UTC as it is from database). I ran into this problem and solved it by adding UTC when I parse time from raw sql strings from database.

```
time_string << " UTC" 
time_object = Time.parse(time_string) # gives time zone as UTC
```

then if you use it, the result will be correct.

Comment: Adding " UTC" to the end of my date worked just fine. Thanks.

Comment: As an alternative (and this will require you to modify the data in your database) you can configure ActiveRecord to use local time instead, which will store the "correct" times in your database and you won't have to sprinkle conversion code throughout your app.

Answer (score 3):

Rails does this on purpose.  Check your time zone settings:

- config.active_record.default_timezone
- config.time_zone

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-record

Time zone features were introduced in 2.1 and haven't changed much.  This article gives a good explanation:
http://mad.ly/2008/04/09/rails-21-time-zone-support-an-overview/

Comment: It doesn't seem that `config.time_zone` (or `config.` anything) works in Rails 3. I get `/home/jason/snip/config/environment.rb:9: undefined local variable or method 'config'`

Comment: Plus if I go to the console and type `Time.zone`, it shows Eastern, which is correct. For all my parsing I'm doing `Time.zone.parse` as opposed to `Time.parse`.

Comment: @Jason in Rails 3, you should put config variables in the Application Object (application.rb) *not* environment.rb. See http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#rails-application-object

Comment: @Jason ActiveRecord automatically does the time zone conversion when you save the object.